# how to set mulitple text in d3 treemap?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width',800)
  .attr('height',500)
d3.json('mydata.json',function (data){
 var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
   .size([800,500])
   .nodes(data)
 var cells = canvas.selectAll(".cell")
   .data(treemap)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class","cell")
 cells.append("rect")
   .attr("x",function (d) { return d.x; })
   .attr("y",function (d) { return d.y; })
   .attr("width",function (d) { return d.dx; })  
   .attr("height",function (d) { return d.dy; }) 
   .attr("fill",function (d) { return d.children ? null : color(d.parent.name); })
   .attr("stroke",'#fff')    
 cells.append("text")
   .attr("x",function (d) { return d.x + d.dx / 2 })
   .attr("y",function (d) { return d.y + d.dy / 2 })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function (d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; })   
})  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my d3 code for creating treemap..in text part i have to display multiple text.,now it display d.name alone but i have to dispaly d.name and d.value...how to display multiple text in d3 treemap?

{
    "name": "Max",
    "value": 100,
    "children": [
    {
      "name": "Sylvia",
      "value": 75,
      "children": [
      {"name": "Craig","value": 25},
      {"name": "Robin","value": 25},
      {"name": "Anna","value": 25}
      ]
    },
    {
    "name": "David",
    "value": 75,
    "children":[
     {"name": "jeff", "value": 25},
     {"name": "Buffy", "value": 25}
     ]
    },
    {
    "name":"Mr X",
    "value":75
    }
    ]
}
this is my json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add another text for values and adjust the y.

```
cells.append("text")
  .attr("x",function (d) { return d.x + d.dx / 2 })
  .attr("y",function (d) { return d.y + d.dy / 2 + 15 })//15 pixels below the name label.
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function (d) { return d.children ? null : d.value; })
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sBeQzBaZzDce1pTkP93U?p=preview)